# TeXstudio 3.0.0 equations do not preview, even though I have the option enabled

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, preview

This is similar to the issue [Roland Salz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338368/texstudio-equation-preview-does-not-work-anymore) had, but I have already followed the advice in that post, and toggled that setting, and restarted, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

It seems like me that it's a bug in 3.0.0, since with the version (2.12.22) I had on my old laptop, it worked fine.
Is this a known issue, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It has been confirmed that it is a bug on the Windows version. [Source](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1234)